# How to prioritize explicit ssh key from commandline over ssh-agent keys?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I have a bunch of ssh keys loaded semi-permanently into ssh-agent. `ssh-add -L` lists 6 keys.

I also have other keys which are stored separately; let's say, on a USB stick. I exactly *don't* want to keep them handy all the time. Let me call one of them `square.key`.

The problem is this: on those occasions when I need `square.key`, I'm okay with plugging the USB stick and specifying `-i /path/to/square.key` — but it **doesn't work**. `-v` reveals why:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ulidtko/.ssh/key1 RSA SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ulidtko/.ssh/key2 RSA SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: key3@localhost ED25519 SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: key4@localhost RSA SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: key5@localhost ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: key6@localhost ECDSA SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /path/to/square.key ED25519 SHA256:<redacted> explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ulidtko/.ssh/key1 RSA SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ulidtko/.ssh/key2 RSA SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: key3@localhost ED25519 SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: key4@localhost RSA SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: key5@localhost ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:<redacted> agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: key6@localhost ECDSA SHA256:<redacted> agent
Received disconnect from 46.101.206.106 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 46.101.206.106 port 22
```

Somehow, `ssh` thinks it's a great idea to try every key from `ssh-agent` BEFORE the `square.key` which I pass manually on the command line. And so this triggers `Too many authentication failures` on the server; `square.key` is never offered.

Is there a way to override or configure this order? I'd like to continue using `ssh-agent`, but `ssh` to respect my manually-set commandline flags, and try the `-i` "explicit" keys first.

Comment: FYI, this is an open issue at https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3153

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**IdentitiesOnly=yes** is probably an appropriate option.That is, using only the specified Identities.

```
ssh -i /path/to/square.key -o IdentitiesOnly=yes remote.server.net
```

or

```
Host remote.server.net
  IdentityFile /path/to/square.key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Enabling `IdentitiesOnly=yes` **globally** has satisfactorily resolved the issue for me, at last. It kinda makes not much sense to have "default keys" configured for authenticating to *any server* you'd ssh into — this is a stupid idea, yet is the default of openssh. Now, with global `IdentitiesOnly=yes`, each server-key association is explicitly configured in my `Host foobar.example.net` blocks, and ssh won't even try any keys before I configure it permanently or temporarily ask via `-i`. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Sadly `IdentitiesOnly` doesn't help when what you're trying to do is pass an alternate key for a host that *does* have an `IdentityFile` set in the config file (e.g. multiple GitHub or BitBucket accounts, since they identify what user you are by the SSH key you present). :(

Answer (score 8):

One workaround is to **pass `IdentityAgent=none`**, either on the same commandline:

```
ssh -i /path/to/square.key -o IdentityAgent=none remote.server.net
```

or equivalently, via the `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remote.server.net
    IdentityFile /path/to/square.key
    IdentityAgent none
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# .ssh/config

host default
hostname 185.xxx.xxx.xxx
user root
port 10xxx
IdentityFile .ssh/debian
IdentityAgent none
```